# How to add the custom Data to calendar list in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, calendar, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I created the Customs Form as a web part, In that form, there have Several Fields like Title, Location, Date and Time picker, Description, Images and URL. After Filling the Form, a user clicks publish button means data should be inserted into SharePoint calendar list. If user clicks add button in calendar list means our custom dialogue needs to come. I looked into following links, But I need more reference about this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/office/dn531433.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have a calendar list, and the issue is clicking the “Add” button launches the list’s default out of the box content type New form, not your custom form.

When you refer to your custom form, my assumption is that you are referring to a custom event content type that can be added to the calendar list.  If that is the case, 1) add your custom content type to the list, 2) and then modify the “Change New Button Order” settings and position the custom content type as the first available option.  The default action for a calendar’s “Add” button is to open the content type in the first position.

If you are referring to a form that is not associated with an event content type, are you able to modify the calendar’s default New form by 1) hiding the list web part and 2) adding a link to your custom form?  However, this would require users to click twice to get to your form, which isn’t ideal.  Another option would be to point users to a web page that displays the calendar, versus accessing the calendar itself.  On the web page you can include a prominent link to your custom form.   If a user’s eye is drawn to the link text for the custom form, they may be less inclined to click the “Add” button in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint designer open calendar list you are customizing.
In right column, in middle window **Forms**, choose your custom form.
Click on it once, than in upper left corner of window click on **FORMS** tab. Click on **Set as default** button and that's it.